# Unable to make file editable on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, apache2, terminal

I'm trying to edit the httpd.conf file located in /private/etc/apache2, and I can't figure out how to get permission to write

I've done

```
$ cd /private/etc/apache2
$ sudo chown bdh httpd.conf
$ ls -lash
 0 drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel   442B Jun  7 00:11 .
 0 drwxr-xr-x  93 root      wheel   3.1K Jun 26 10:51 ..
 0 drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel   442B Jan  3 16:26 extra
24 -r--r--r--   1 bdh       wheel    24K Jun  7 00:11 httpd.conf
 ...etc...
$ vim httpd.conf
```

and it says `"httpd.conf" [readonly] 677L, 24330C`

tried `cp`ing to the desktop, but I cant get permission to edit it there either

I'm pretty new to using the terminal, is there some other command I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normally unnecessary and undesirable to alter access permissions to edit a file. To edit a file that requires administrator (or other user) privileges without altering the access permissions, use:

```
sudo -e /private/etc/apache2
```

Sudo's `-e` option tells it you want to edit the given file.

This command copies the file and makes it writable by you, tells the editor specified with the SUDO_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables (they're checked in that order) to edit the file, and when the editor exits, the file is copied back to the original without altering its access permissions.

See the sudo man page for details: x-man-page://8/sudo

Answer (score 2):

The chmod command is what you're looking for I believe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod
chmod 777 will let anyone read, write or execute for instance.

As richardhsu correctly added, 744 is RWX, R--,R-- and thats probably what you want.

Comment: Probably don't want to make your conf file writable by others so you should set it to 744 so that it's rwx for owner and r for group and world. Or better yet 644 since you most likely don't need to execute the file.

Comment: Agreed.  My example was just to explain the concept.  But thats a better command.  Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Hey thank you for taking your time to respond. I'll have to look more into chmod